# SQL Server table design

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table containing about 30 columns. 10 of the columns can only be populated from a list of values.

Right now these values are stored as `varchar`, straight in the table.

Should I create separate tables for these values and map the 2 tables with a foreign key on the IDs?

Will it improve performance if there are IDs instead of words? Or will it decrease performance because when we query we have to join all the time? Or does it not make a difference in performance?

I am also concerned about the integrity of the data.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You described to us what you have, and you described to us what you might do. But you did not tell us what is wrong. You are wondering about performance, but in my experience performance is only a problem if you have established a specific performance goal and you have developed your entire system and you test and you see that the system does not meet that goal.

Answer (score 3):

Foreign Keys are a relational integrity tool, not a performance tool. At least in SQL Server, the creation of an FK does not create an associated index, and you should create indexes on all FK fields to improve look up times.

So, FKs don't boost performance, but making indexes will :)

Comment: +1 but using foreign keys does boost data integrity, which is quite frankly a lot more important than a tiny hit on performance...

Comment: @aF: I was thinking of doing IDs for integrity purposes and also for normalization, because of dulicate data.

Comment: @aF: On the other hand I'm concerned about performance because of the joins. I'm also wondering if Fks can improve performance on searches when matching text data.

Comment: like @marc_s stated they may improve a tiny hit on performance, but you really can use `indexes` to make it work :) FKs + indexes is the way to go!